# Django custom user error

Tags: django, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

I have a custom user model that extends an AbstractBaseUser, as well as my own user manager (GenericUserManager):

```
class GenericUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password, key_expires):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        if not username:
            raise ValueError("users must have a username")

        if not password:
            raise ValueError('users must have password')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            key_expires=key_expires,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
       return self.get(username=username)

class BaseRegistrationUser(AbstractBaseUser):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
     email = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name='email address',
            max_length=255,
            unique=False,
        )
     activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=90)
     key_expires = models.DateTimeField()
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     date_joined = models.DateTimeField(('date joined'), 
     default=datetime.datetime.now)
     is_merchant_or_customer = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
     REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username, email']

     def __str__(self):
        return self.username

     ...

     def natural_key(self):
        return (self.email,)

     ...
class Customer(BaseRegistrationUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="", null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="", null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=175, default="", null=True)

    objects = GenericUserManager()
    ...
```

These work fine for registration purposes, however, whenever I attempt to log a 'customer' user I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\OEM\Documents\repos\repo\ecommerce\myapp\views.py" in get_profile
  126.     user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

File "C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in authenticate
  70.             user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, 
request, credentials)

File "C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in _authenticate_with_backend
  115.     return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)

File "C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py" in authenticate
  18.             user = 
UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /get-profile/
Exception Value: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

I don't know what causes this since the 'get_by_natural_key' attribute is defined in my UserManager.

I've tried new database migrations and spent a solid 3 days just combing through other questions on this site, but unfortunately, it hasn't helped. I would be extremely grateful someone could help me figure this out.

EDIT:Fixed the indenting, but the error persists

Comment: the function must be inside the class

Comment: where you call your get_by_natural_key ? in views.py file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution, in hindsight, should have been more obvious. I correctly assigned the customer my `user manager` class, however, I had not applied the same to my `BaseRegistrationUser`, which meant that it was missing the required methods to log in using the django.auth methods

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your indentation is wrong. `get_by_natural_key()` is a function, not a method of your manager class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have fixed the indenting, but the problem still exists. I think the indenting may have just occurred when I put the code into stack overflow since my own code has the correct indenting.

Comment: Sorry, @LeanderHach, I can't see what you're trying to do. It would be helpful if you could include a complete, runnable example of your code. I created [udjango](https://github.com/donkirkby/udjango) as a way to post runnable examples for Django code. See if it helps for this problem.